# Adding source code to docker image using dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a source code and I want to add it into docker image using Dockerfile. I use COPY command, but I don't know what I should put in destination place. Can you tell me if destination is a specific directory or it is optional?

Comment: Which docker image you are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any destination path , but make sure that path exist for example

COPY source_code / opt/folder_name

Then optionally you can make this in docker as working directory

WORKDIR /opt/folder_name

Comment: its not WORDIR. its WORKDIR

`WORKDIR  /opt/folder_name`

Answer (score 5):

The destination directory can be a directory of your choice.

```
    ...

    RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
    COPY ./src /usr/src/app

    ...
```

The above commands in a Dockerfile would create /usr/src/app in the containers filesystem and the COPY would copy the contents of the src directory on the host to /usr/src/app in the containers filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

in Dockerfile:

```
COPY ./src /dst
```

Where *src* is a folder in the same path of Dockerfile on the host (the computer on which Docker is directly running). *dst* is a folder on the container itself.

Here is an example:

[Create a Dockerfile for an ASP.NET Core application](https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/#create-a-dockerfile-for-an-aspnet-core-application)

> # Copy everything
>
> `COPY . /FolderInTheContainer/`

this will copy everything in the same path of Dockerfile, to a destination folder in the container.

---

Here is `dockerfile copy` documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy