# Docker for custom build process

Tags: docker, azure-container-instances

I have an executable that performs a number of tasks such as:

1. Copy .NET source code to a directory
2. Run another executable that modifies the source code
3. Run MSBuild to build the code
4. Publish the code
5. Run add-migration to create database
6. Run another executable that populates the database from files
   etc.

I've set this up on my laptop, and everything works correctly, and now I want to publish this to the cloud.

Is it possible to create a docker image that does all these kinds of things, and run it on Azure Container Instances?  Or do I need to run this kind of system on a VM?

I'm new to docker so don't know what it's capable of, but if I can run it on ACI as-needed that would be great, so I'm not paying for a VM 24/7 when this process only happens a few times a day

Comment: you can definitely. just try and tell us errors. (if you don't tell what you tried, we may close the question)

Comment: Thanks for confirming Lei Yang, I'll give it a go :)

Answer (score 1):

**Docker is an open source centralised plateform design to create, Deploy and run Application.Its uses OS level of virtualization.Docker uses container on host to run the application.Container is also like a Virtaul Machine but its advantage, there is no preallocation of RAM as we have in VM.**

> Is it possible to create a docker image that does all these kinds of
> things, and run it on Azure Container Instances? Or do I need to run
> this kind of system on a VM?

Yes it is possible to create docker images using docker compose yaml file . In that yaml file you need to write all the task you want to peroform and then build an images of that file and push it container registery and create a conatainer instance of it.

You can take reference of these thread for [**Copy source code and to add it into docker image using Dockerfile**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47951183/adding-source-code-to-docker-image-using-dockerfile).and [**how to create database in docker container using yaml file**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808069/how-to-create-database-in-database-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Rahul, great to know it's possible... I'll give it a go